# Is there a way to allow \w inside character sets in vim regex?

Tags: regex, vim

Sorry this is quite a simple question but I am unable to google for it effectively.

Basically, I expect `:s/\v\w+/foo/` to behave the same as `:s/\v[\w]+/foo/` but the latter that puts `\w` within a character set does not match anything.

Is there a flag to enable this? is this not supported?

Thanks and sorry for the simplistic question. by the way, I know about `[:alnum:]` and things or that I could use `[a-zA-Z]` or something similar (possibly with underscores, I can't remember), but was looking for a way of using one consistent, quick notation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you can't. You'll find that information at `:help /[`, actually near `:help /\]`:

> ```
>   - The following translations are accepted when the 'l' flag is not
>     included in 'cpoptions' {not in Vi}:
>     ...
>     NOTE: The other backslash codes mentioned above do not work inside
>     []!
> ```

The equivalent collection for `\w` is `[_[:alnum:]]`. You can also combine `\w` with a collection, like this: `\%(\w\|[...]\)`.

Comment: I have just come back to this and decided I don't like the fact that this is unimplemented, do you know if it is known as a bug in vim (I can't find [anything here about it](https://code.google.com/p/vim/issues/list?can=2&q=regex&colspec=ID+Type+Status+Priority+Milestone+Owner+Summary&cells=tiles)) or whether this occurs for a specific reason? I'm wanting to look into fixing this (as I consider it a problem, non-consistent syntax) but need to check that it isn't done for some reason I don't understand.

Comment: This is not a bug, the rules within regexp collections are just different. I don't know any other regexp engine that allows that.

Comment: And you won't be able to handle _all_ `\x` atoms: For example `\d` matches digits, but inside a collection, `[\d123]` includes a character by decimal codepoint. That's a conflict you cannot resolve, and I don't think Bram would accept an incomplete solution (but ask on vim_dev if you must).

Comment: no, thank you, that's why I was asking here to try and understand why it wasn't allowed. I wasn't aware of the decimal codepoint case.

Comment: Also, general [PCRE's](http://www.pcre.org/) support this (ruby example: `"hello".match /[\w]+/ #=> #<MatchData "hello">`, perl example: `echo foo |perl -ne 'print if /[\w]+/' #=> foo`) [link to documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions) (under Character Classes.)

Comment: Interesting find, and it fits Perl's TIMTOWTDI approach. Apparently, they don't have this conflict.